# Can I return a list of arrays from a promise in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to return a list of arrays in a promise in typescript.
This is my implementation and it's not working out. I need serious help on this one.

```
const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {    
    let onbidJobs:any = [...objects];
    let awardedJobs:any = [...objects];
    let completedJobs:any = [...objects];

    //return the jobs
    resolve({
        onbid: onbidJobs,
        awarded: awardedJobs,
        completed: completedJobs
    });
});

let returnedonbid:any;
let returnedaward:any;

promise.then((resolve) => {
   this.returnedaward = resolve.awarded;
   this.returnedonbid = resolve.onbid;  //<-- I really want to return my arrays like this
});
```

Comment: The above code should work. What is currently returned in `resolve` (`console.log()` inside the `then()` callback)?

Comment: On second look: are the jobs async operations themselves?

Comment: *not working out* How? Is there a chance you are trying to access `this.returnedonbid` outside of the `then` handler--before it's been populated?

Comment: my error is [ts] Property 'onbid' does not exist on type '{}'.
any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `: any`. Instead define the actual types of the objects where possible. In addition, you should define the `Promise` return type like so:

```
const promise = new Promise<{onbid:any, awarded:any, completed:any}>((resolve, reject) => { ...
```

Once you define the `Promise`'s return type, you'll get type info on the `then`'s argument.

You can also use an interface to bundle the type so it doesn't bloat your code, especially if you need it more than once.

Comment: @EmekaObianom, I think you may have missed something in your edit... you should avoid using `any` unless there is no way for you to know what the type would be. But otherwise, I think you got the essence of things.